# How to have certain solutions/projects always show up on start page of Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have a situation where I always want to show two solution files always at the top on Visual Studio 2013 start up page as show in screen shot below, since these solutions are very critical to my development. I do not work with these solutions on a daily/frequent basis.

If I open other solutions then these 2 solutions get moved out of the list shown on start up page.

**Question** : Is it possible to have these solutions always show up on start up page and if yes, then how would I do it?

[image: Solutions in Startup Page in VS2013]

Comment: As you hover over the recent project there should be an option to `pin this item to the recent projects list` . it will move to the top and be there every time you start up VS

Comment: @Nkosi. That's excellent tip. I never knew this.  Please post this as an answer.

Comment: not a problem. glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you hover over the recent project there should be an option to `pin this item to the recent projects list`. It will move to the top and be there every time you start up VS